# Python-pip : Invoice2data package installation error through pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install invoice2data package through pip but i am getting the following error :

> ```
> ERROR: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/home/webwerks/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py",
> line 178, in main status = self.run(options, args) File
> "/home/webwerks/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py",
> line 414, in run use_user_site=options.use_user_site, File
> "/home/webwerks/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py",
> line 58, in install_given_reqs
> **kwargs File "/home/webwerks/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py",
> line 922, in install use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
> File
> "/home/webwerks/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py",
> line 448, in move_wheel_files
> warn_script_location=warn_script_location, File
> "/home/webwerks/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py",
> line 428, in move_wheel_files assert info_dir, "%s .dist-info
> directory not found" % req AssertionError: invoice2data .dist-info
> directory not found
> ```

```
Ubuntu : 16.04  
python : Python 2.7.12  
pip : pip 19.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

I have tried uninstalling `pip` completely and then reinstalling again still I get the same error. Also tried other StackOverflow solutions but still it didn't help.

Answer (score -2):

i tried the command in python 3.7.2 and it was installed succesfully. This is the command used
"python -m pip install invoice2data"